# What is the best method for storing large paragraph's of text?

Tags: android, storing-information

I am currently creating a wiki-like application and currently have multiple large paragraphs of text that is required to be stored. What is the best way to store such information? Should I use a database or just put all the information in a text file or even just store the information as a string in xml? The information won't be able to be altered currently by users but I might change that in the future possibly?

Just wondering whats the best method :)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For large data it's better to use a database (more control of data flow and more structuring), and keep in mind if you want to work with android database use it just for storing information that is needed when user is not connected to the internet or certain information that is important for the user.

```
scenario related to your app:
- An article that the user selected as favorite
```

And keep the unnecessary data on your server.

To use the android database, `ROOM` is a good start, find the link below to start implementing `ROOM` in your application:
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room

If you need further information feel free to ask